# How to get pipe (|) delimiters between FIX tags in a UNIX command for FIX logs?

Tags: unix, fix-protocol

I am able to get spaces between tags by running:

```
tail -f filename | tr '\001' ' '
```

but I would like the tail output to have `|` delimiters, i.e.

> 35=D|49=sender|56=recipient

anyone know how? thanks

Comment: Please format your post with adapted [markdown](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: I fixed your question's formatting.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Don't you simply want this?

```
tail -f filename | tr '\001' '|'
                              ^
                              replace space with pipe!
```

`\001` is ASCII character 1, also known as SOH ("start of heading").  FIX uses this character as the field separator, i.e. it follows every "tag=value" element.

The unix `tr` command simply replaces all instances of the first parameter (`\001` above) with the second parameter (`|`).

Comment: what does \001 represent?

Comment: It's ASCII character 1 aka the SOH character.  I've added more to my answer to explain this.

Comment: Thank you again Grant, that is a really clear explanation

Comment: No problem.  If your question is resolved, please "accept" this answer so that SO will mark it as resolved.

Comment: I have found that when using this, if i add a grep afterwards or before it tends to kind stop the tail from working as expected. It sort of splutters or doesnt update at all, for example: tail -f filename | tr '\001' '|' | grep abc

Comment: any ideas or thoughts on that?

Comment: Sorry, no, I don't have any insight into that.